# Function to split sentence words to get only first capital letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am trying to create a function for Python 3.6.1 where a user can insert a sentence and the output will be the first letters of each word following . and space. i.e Hello World --> H. W.

I created the code below but i cannot manage to make it work correctly. I am getting only the first word letter and somehow it ignores the second or third word etc. Any ideas how it can be fixed?

```
def initials(text):
    x = ""
    for text in text.split():
          x += text[0].upper()+". "
          return x

st= input("give sentance:")
print(initials(st))
```

Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

give sentance: hello world
H.

I would expect H. W.

Thank you!

Comment: Unindent your `return` statement. Your function currently returns after the first iteration of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def initials(text):
    text += " " # add a space to the end of text
    result = ""
    # str.find returns -1 if the specified string is not found
    while text.find(" ")>-1:
        # the if statement gets rid of extra spaces so they are
        # not included in the initials
        if text[0] != " ":
            result += text[0].upper() + ". "
        text = text[text.find(" ")+1:]
    return result

st= input("give sentance:")
print(initials(st))
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code should look simply like this :

```
sen = input("Please enter a string ")
sen = sen.split()
for i in sen:
    num = i[0]
    print(num,end="")
```

It would print the first letters of your each word!